# Grab libraries from another project and reference them in a new one via YAML in build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to use library from another project in Azure build pipeline. My project depends on that reference.

```
pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
steps:
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    buildType: specific
    project: '8d7f1dea-4875-48da-9521-1761f7925dec'
    pipeline: 4
    artifactName: drop
    itemPattern: |
     drop/CSC.Automation/CSC.Automation.dll
     drop/CSC.Automation/CSC.dll

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
  enabled: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

the above YAML code shows me grabbing an artifact and the exact two libraries i need in the current project.  Since the current project is missing those libraries I need it to reference them. Anythoughts?

Comment: Ideally, cross-project dependencies are published to an artifacts feed and consumed as versioned packages.

Comment: sorry you had me half way, but the tail of that sentence doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Think "nuget packages"